# How to switch between local and release version of dependency in monorepo?

Tags: npm, repository, node-modules, dependency-management, monorepo

I have a monorepo with an app and two related modules:

```
monorepo/app (imports module-b)
monorepo/packages/module-a (imports module-b)
monorepo/packages/module-b
```

`module-a` and `module-b` are also published for external usage.

What is the best way to specify `module-b` in the package.json of `app` and `module-a`, so I can use local version of `module-b` in development, but the release version of `module-b` when releasing `app` and `module-a`?

For example, in `module-a` I'm currently switching between `npm install "file:../packages/module-b` in local development and `npm install module-b` after releasing `module-b`, but before publishing `module-a`. I feel like there should be a better way to switch between local and release version of `module-b`.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, were you able to solve this?

Comment: We solved it using [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-link/) in local development and overwriting the version with a custom script in our release pipeline.